# how to retrieve files from amazon emr?

Tags: java, file, apache-spark, amazon-emr

My Apache Spark application takes various input files and stores the results and logs in other files. The input files are provided along with the application which is supposed to run on the Amazon cloud (EMR seemed preferable to EC2).

Now, I know that I'm supposed to create an uber-jar containing my input files and the application that accesses them. However, how do I retrieve the generated files from the cloud, once the execution finishes?

As an additional info, the files are created and written using relative paths from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want to access the output generated by the Spark application outside the cluster, the usual thing to do is to write it to S3. Then you may of course read the data directly from S3 from outside the EMR cluster.

Comment: That would mean I'd have to initialize my application with the S3 path?
For example, PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("s3:\\log\\logfile.txt", "UTF-8").